# The entity type List requires a primary key to be defined

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm using .NET 5 and Entity Framework as ORM. I want to use a code-first database approach.

I have 2 entity classes:

```
public class PurchaseOrderItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PurnchaseOrder")]
    public int PurnchaseOrderId { get; set; }
    public PurchaseOrder PurchaseOrder { get; set; }
}

public class PurchaseOrder
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime  CreationDate { get; set; }
    public List<PurchaseOrderItem> PurchaseOrderItems { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public double TotalPrice
    {
        get
        {
            return PurchaseOrderItems.Sum(x => x.Price);
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to add new migration, I get the error like this:

> The entity type 'List' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'. For more information on keyless entity types, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2141943.

Also my db context class:

```
public class ItemsAppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ItemsAppDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<AppUser> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PurchaseOrderItem> PurchaseOrderItems { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PurchaseOrder> PurchaseOrders { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<PurchaseOrder>()
                    .HasOne(p => p.PurchaseOrderItems)
                    .WithMany()
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to add a key to your PurnchaseOrderItem.cs.

Comment: I have key properties on both of PurnchaseOrderItem and PurnchaseOrder entities.

Comment: What EF version you use ?

Comment: I'm using version 5

Comment: Try to define `Key` explicitly like `modelBuilder.Entity<PurnchaseOrder>().HasKey(x => x.Id);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update below code in your ItemsAppDbContext

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<PurnchaseOrder>()
    .HasMany(p => p.PurnchaseOrderItems)
    .WithOne(g => g.PurnchaseOrder).HasForeignKey(s=>s.PurnchaseOrderId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
}
```

Read [this](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/configure-one-to-many-relationship-using-fluent-api-in-ef-core.aspx) to know more.